# Adding Facebook link to on website to our facebook

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, graphical-logo

Am I allowed to use a Facebook logo to link to my Facebook from our web page. I would basically like to use a visual link versus just the word Facebook on the bottom of the page that will link to our page.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the Facebook [Brand Permissions Center](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/index.php) contains all the guidelines for this.

In particular, the [Logo and Trademarks](http://www.facebook.com/brandpermissions/logos.php) tab states the difference between using the full Facebook logo and the 'f' logo.